# How to migrate from python 2.7 urllib2.Request to python 3.10 urllib.requests.Request, and encode data in a compatible way?

Tags: python, json, request, urllib

I'm trying to port some code from python 2.7 which uses `urllib2.Request`, to python 3.10, and use the newer `json.dumps()` function and the `urllib.requests.Request` class. My problem is that the server accepts Posts from the original code, but fails with an in internal 500 error when I use updated classes. I expect the issue is that I am not encoding my data into the format the server requires. Both versions of `post()` here are supposed to pass the bytes of a png image, within a dict, to a web service running on localhost.
Here is the original function, which works in python 2.7:

```
def post(self, endpoint, data={}, params={}, headers=None):
    try:
        url = self.base_url + endpoint + "?" + urllib.urlencode(params)
        data = json.dumps(data, False)  # which parameter gets the False value?
        headers = headers or {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json"}
        request = urllib2.Request(url=url, data=data, headers=headers)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        data = response.read()
        data = json.loads(data)
        return data
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.exception("ERROR: ApiClient.post")
```

Here are the docs from the python 2.7 `Request` [https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib2.htm](https://%20https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib2.htm)l

> class urllib2.Request(url[, data][, headers][, origin_req_host][,
> unverifiable]) This class is an abstraction of a URL request.
>
> url should be a string containing a valid URL.
>
> data may be a string specifying additional data to send to the server,
> or None if no such data is needed. Currently HTTP requests are the
> only ones that use data; the HTTP request will be a POST instead of a
> GET when the data parameter is provided. data should be a buffer in
> the standard application/x-www-form-urlencoded format. The
> urllib.urlencode() function takes a mapping or sequence of 2-tuples
> and returns a string in this format.

Here are the docs for python 3.10  https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request

> class urllib.request.Request(url, data=None, headers={},
> origin_req_host=None, unverifiable=False, method=None)
>
> This class is an abstraction of a URL request.
>
> url should be a string containing a valid URL.
>
> data must be an object specifying additional data to send to the
> server, or None if no such data is needed. Currently HTTP requests are
> the only ones that use data. The supported object types include bytes,
> file-like objects, and iterables of bytes-like objects. If no
> Content-Length nor Transfer-Encoding header field has been provided,
> HTTPHandler will set these headers according to the type of data.
> Content-Length will be used to send bytes objects, while
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked as specified in RFC 7230, Section 3.3.1
> will be used to send files and other iterables. For an HTTP POST
> request method, data should be a buffer in the standard
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded format. The urllib.parse.urlencode()
> function takes a mapping or sequence of 2-tuples and returns an ASCII
> string in this format. It should be encoded to bytes before being used
> as the data parameter.

And this is my replacement function and decoder, which fails when I submit it to `urlopen()`

```
class BytesEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, bytes):
            return base64.b64encode(o).decode('utf-8')
        else:
            return super().default(o)


    def post(self, endpoint, dict_in={}, params={}, headers=None):
        try:
            url = self.base_url + endpoint + "?" + urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
            # NOTE: In the original code, the string returned by json.dumps is sent directly to urllib2.Request.
            # That changes in urllib.request.Request, where the data parameter specifies "bytes"
            # Original line was "data = json.dumps(data, False)"
            json_str: str = json.dumps(dict_in, sort_keys=True, indent=2, cls=BytesEncoder)
            json_bytes: bytes = json_str.encode('utf-8')
            headers = headers or {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json"}
            request_out = urllib.request.Request(url=url, data=json_bytes, headers=headers)
            """
            FIXME: The following urlopen raises HTTPError
             url=http://127.0.0.1:7860/sdapi/v1/img2img?, code=500, reason=Internal Server Error
             #/components/schemas/StableDiffusionProcessingImg2Img
            """
            response = urlopen(request_out)
            response_json_str = response.read()
            response_dict = json.loads(response_json_str)
            return response_dict
        except urllib.error.HTTPError as ex:
            StabDiffAuto1111.LOGGER.exception("ERROR: ApiClient.post()")
            message = "url=%s, code=%d, reason=%s" % (ex.url, ex.code, ex.reason)
            StabDiffAuto1111.LOGGER.error(message)
            StabDiffAuto1111.LOGGER.error(str(ex.headers))
```

My replacement function does several things differently. First, I pass a custom `BytesEncoder` to `json.dumps()`. If I don't use a custom encoder, then `json.dumps()` fails with a "cannot serialize bytes" error. But perhaps I should use something besides base64 to encode the bytes.
Next, instead of re-using whatever was passed as the "data" argument, I create intermediate variables, with the expected type hints. So all is explicitly clear.
Finally, I take the (unicode) string from `json.dumps`, and I encode that into utf-8 bytes. That was my understanding of the documentation sentence "It should be encoded to bytes before being used as the data parameter." But I expect this is what the server won't accept.

How do I post the data in the same format that the previous function did?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was not just in the one function I was trying to upgrade, but basically everywhere the old code converts from `str` to `bytes` or vice-versa, AND wherever python 3 functions specify `bytes` where python 2 assumes `str`. In particular, old code that generated a base64 encoded `str` in python 2.7, generates a `List[bytes]` in python 3. So I needed start by appending `.decode('utf-8')` to all calls to `base64.b64encode()`

This migration issue is well documented, once you know what the issue is :/ And until you know, it's tough to figure out, because in python 3, `str`, `bytes`, and `List[bytes]` are sometimes treated as the same, and sometimes differently.

Once I tracked down all the confusions of `bytes` vs. `str`, the following function works as expected:

```
def post(self, endpoint, dict_in={}, params={}, headers=None):  # noqa
try:
    url = self.base_url + endpoint + "?" + urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
    # NOTE: In the original code, the string returned by json.dumps is sent directly to urllib2.Request.
    # That changes in urllib.request.Request, where the data parameter specifies "bytes"
    json_str: str = json.dumps(dict_in, sort_keys=True, indent=2)
    json_bytes: bytes = json_str.encode('utf-8')

    headers = headers or {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json"}
    request_out = urllib.request.Request(url=url, data=json_bytes, headers=headers)
    response = urlopen(request_out)
    response_json_str = response.read()
    response_dict = json.loads(response_json_str)

    return response_dict
except urllib.error.HTTPError as ex:
    LOGGER.exception("ERROR: ApiClient.post()")
    message = "url=%s, code=%d, reason=%s" % (ex.url, ex.code, ex.reason)
    LOGGER.error(message)
    LOGGER.error(str(ex.headers))
```